# facebook opengraph actions on application tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

i have a facebook page. I added an application as a tab to page. My application is a voting game. Im created an action and objects. Ive submitted and there's no problem. But my application's url is not true on submitted action's preview on user's timeline.

for example:

My page's url: http://www.facebook.com/brandname

My application's url: http://www.facebook.com/brandname/app_xxxxxxxxxxx

But my application's url is http://www.facebook.com/coolestgame  (coolestgame is my application's App Namespace) on action's preview on timeline.

How can i display right url?

Answer (score 1):

The way user actions work are

-User clicks button to post to timeline
- facebook goes to the url the action has pointed to.
 - Looks for the meta tag og:url and this is the url that will be displayed on the user action on the timeline.

If you but in your url 'http://www.facebook.com/coolestgame' , This will be seen as a profile. So the way I have it done is. I have an intermediate page where the user action is pointed to eg  appNamespace:buy?product=intermediatePage.aspx.

on this page the metatag url is intermediatePage.aspx.

Then when the people come in from clicking the action on the timeline i redirect them to where i want them to go.

Hope this helps